# Error indexOf with number negative jQuery, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which collects the value of an input that is in string format, being in this format I need to delete the words and only leave the numbers using the replace option, previously I used the **first indexOf tag (it works correctly)** to know if in the value of the input it contains the character **"-"** and to know if the numeric that is inside the string is negative positive, once the character is detected and all the words have been eliminated, what I do in the case that in the first IndexOf is equal to 0 is to convert the replaced value to negative, after that another function calls the first function and collects the variable that contains the replaced result and passed to negative, in this second function it contains another indexOF (it does NOT work correctly) that reads if the character "-" in the variable that we have passed since the first function. I have the **problem in this second IndexOf** which gives me the following error: **impuesto1.indexOf is not a function**.

**First function** (working correctly)

```
    function value_impuestos(){
    
            if(un_articulo == true)

            {   
                impuestos1=$("#impuestos1-1").val();
                negativo_positivo=impuestos1.indexOf("-");
                impuesto = impuestos1.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
            
            
                if(negativo_positivo==0)
                {
                     x = impuesto;
                     impuesto = x * -1;
                     impuesto=parseFloat(impuesto);
                    
                }
            
            }
        
    }
```

**Second function** (NO working correctly)

```
$("select[id=impuestos1-1]").change(function(){
    value_impuestos();
    impuesto1=impuesto;
    alert(impuesto1);  //result correct, example : -7

        positivo_negativo=impuesto1.indexOf("-") > -1; //ERROR

                if(positivo_negativo==false)
                {
                }
});
```

Comment: First of all [`var/let/const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) you need them. Also `impuesto1` seems to be a number, numbers do not have index of method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be simple, but:

Here is a working example. The change event is fired when you click out of the text box.

```js
let impuesto = 0; 
let un_articulo = true;

function value_impuestos(impuestos1){
      if(un_articulo)
      {   
          negativo_positivo = impuestos1.indexOf("-");
          impuesto = impuestos1.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
          try {
            impuesto=parseFloat(impuesto); 
          }
          catch(err) {
            console.error(err)
          }          

          console.log('value_impuestos:', impuesto)
          console.log('impuesto type:', typeof impuesto)

          if(negativo_positivo == 0)
          {
               impuesto = impuesto * -1;
          }
          return impuesto
      }
  }

$(function() {
  $("input[id=impuestos1-1]").change(function(e){
      let impuesto1 = value_impuestos($(this).val());
      console.log('change:', impuesto1)
      if(impuesto1 > -1)
      {
        console.log('positive or 0')
      }else{
        console.log('negative')
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="impuestos1-1" /> 
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: in this way it does not enter the IF it seems that impuesto1 does not recognize it as a number

Comment: You can use - console.log(typeof impuesto1) to get the type.

Comment: I have made a console.log typeof and it is string I convert it with parseFloat and I already get type number, but I realize that what is happening is that the variable des of the first function does not receive well since if I do a console. log (impuesto1) already being converted to number with parseaFloat the result that returns me is null and if I keep it as string the result that returns me is "" that is .. nothing

Comment: This might be a good simple read https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Code in the question did not work due to asynchronous nature of code execution... when the first function was called from second function, program does not wait for the first function to complete before executing the next line of code in second function. Due to this you cannot be sure if the value of impuesto has been updated before it is assigned to impuesto1. 99.99% not, because it's right next line of code. Awesome answer by @Kasper